# What is causing this error in Django: NOT NULL constraint failed: mainapp_comment.post_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am in the middle of making a social network web application in Django. I have nailed most of the features needed, but I am stuck on making the commenting system work. I originally had it so users could make their own name for comments, but decided against that.

The posting system has it, so the user who is logged in and makes the post, their name will be displayed for the author of the post. That's why some of the code is copy-pasted between the 2.

I have tried all kinds of things, such as making the view a class instead of a function. It didn't work, and I am back to square one. Right now the user can make a post no problem, however the user's name isn't recorded and I have to set the author manually in the admin interface.

The relevant code in views.py

```py
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'mainapp/post_details.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('mainapp:post_detail',pk=post.pk)
            def form_valid(self, form):
                form.instance.author = self.request.user
                return super().form_valid(form)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'mainapp/comment_form.html',{'form':form})
```

Here is the relevant code from models.py

```py
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,auto_now_add=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mainapp:post_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('mainapp.Post',related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Here is the forms.py file, with the CommentForm class

```py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Comment
        fields = ('text',)
        widgets = {
            'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'textareaclass'}),
        }
```

Here is the bit in views.py that makes the Post system thing I was talking about work

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I am so sorry if this question if long, but thank you in advance :)

At the moment, I am just confused at why this doesn't work. It works for the post system, but I can't really figure out this comment system.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused by the title of your post - I'm not sure why you would be getting a not null constraint failed on `post_id` when you're setting `comment.post` - but the following should work to attach the current user as the author of the comment:

```
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user # add this line
            comment.save()
            return redirect('mainapp:post_detail',pk=post.pk)
            # remove `def form_valid`
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'mainapp/comment_form.html',{'form':form})
```

Note the removal of the `form_valid` inline function definition which only makes sense as a method in the context of a class-based view.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked just how i needed :)